# EaselJS - Having two canvases with different FPS

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

I am experimenting with EaselJS and 2 animation instances using sprite sheets and 2 separate canvases at different positions with the same z-index, they aren't layered.  What I have now are two EaselJS functions each with a different stage and sprite sheet, instance1 being fired with jQuery after DOM load and instance2 with mouseenter/mouseleave events also with jQuery.

EaselJS:

```
function instance1() {
    var stage = new Stage(document.getElementById(canvas1));
    var ss = new SpriteSheet({
        "images": ["sprite1.jpg"], 
        "frames": {"regY": 0, "height": 100, "regX": 0, "width": 200, "count": 17}, 
        "animations": {"instance1": [0, 16]}
    });

        var initInstance1 = new BitmapAnimation(ss);
    initInstance1.x = 0;
    initInstance1.y = 0;
    initInstance1.gotoAndPlay("instance1");

    stage.addChild(initInstance1);
    Ticker.setFPS(10);
    Ticker.addListener(stage);
}
function instance2() {
    var stage = new Stage(document.getElementById(canvas2));
    var ss = new SpriteSheet({
        "images": ["sprite2.jpg"], 
        "frames": {"regY": 0, "height": 100, "regX": 0, "width": 200, "count": 17}, 
        "animations": {"instance2": [0, 16]}
    });

        var initInstance2 = new BitmapAnimation(ss);
    initInstance2.x = 0;
    initInstance2.y = 0;
    initInstance2.gotoAndPlay("instance2");

    stage.addChild(initInstance2);
    Ticker.setFPS(24);
    Ticker.addListener(stage);
}
```

While testing, I found that instead of running at the FPS defined by each function, instance1 will run at 10FPS, then if instance2 is called by mouseenter(); with jQuery, instance1's FPS will automatically change instance2's FPS.  Is there a method of applying a different Ticker to each instance as to retain separate FPS?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/Ticker.html) states that `Ticker` provides a "centralized tick or heartbeat broadcast at a set interval". It also states that it implements a static API and should not be instantiated. It would seem, therefore, that the library does not support the creation of multiple tickers running at different intervals.

24 fps is a far better frame rate for smooth animation than 10. Is it possible to set that as the global and use another value, such as duration for example, to slow the animation on your first instance? Another option might be to set the frame rate to the higher value and implement some code, such as the [jquery throttle plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), to limit the number of calls to the function which animates instance1.

Comment: I'm calling instance1 with no arguments on DOM load e.g. `instance1();`, how could I write something like  `instance1($.throttle(10,this));`?  It doesn't seem to work, thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WUB4W/, no sprites though so it's not functional, but that's basically what my app consists of.  Thanks for taking a look, the throttle plugin you mentioned is a great idea.

Comment: Full-disclosure; I don't know easel. I had imagined that you might have a callback somewhere listening for ticks and acting on your two instances. This would be the place to implement the throttling. However, it looks to me like it's all internal to the library. Presumably doubling the number of frames in the slower animation is not an option?

Comment: I was aiming for a small sprite sheet, so more frames is out of the question.  From searching, I've sen mention of using setInterva(); or setTimeout(); in place of the internal Ticker function to control FPS, haven't come up with an implementation that works yet.

Comment: Have you had a look at the frequency property? I can't find a description in the documentation, but it looks like you might be able to set a global frame rate but reduce the rate of an individual animation by altering the frequency property. Grant Skinner himself mentions it in the following thread, which also gives a hint at how you might implement your own individual timers for animations; namely using those to advance the animation with the gotoAndStop method: http://groups.google.com/group/easeljs/browse_thread/thread/6b484655f4e474ec

Comment: I thought the frequency property was for throttling frame sets declared by the `"animations": {"instance": [start, end ]}` property.  Although I could compress both instance1 & 2 into one sprite sheet which would then enable the frequency property.

Comment: You're more likely to be right as you've clearly spent more time than me looking at easel. It does sound like binning off the internal ticker and implementing your own custom timer(s) to move through your sprite sheets is the way to go here. I'd probably set a single timer running continuously at 24 fps to control both animations and advance the second animation every second tick when the mouse is hovering over your link. Let me know if you're still struggling with it and I'll see if I can knock up a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add your `Stage` objects as listeners to the ticker, try creating your own `tick` function and using it instead. This way you can update your stages as often as you want.

`window.tick = function (delta) {
 ...
};

Ticker.setFPS(20);
Ticker.addListener(window);`

EDIT: alternatively you can leave your code intact and override the `tick` method on your "slower" stage and update only when you need.

Answer (score 0):

To give a working example:

```js
let fps1 = 30,
    fps2 = 15,
    delay1Start = Math.round(60/fps1),
    delay1 = delay1Start,
    delay2Start = Math.round(60/fps2),
    delay2 = delay2Start;

createjs.Ticker.framerate = 60;
createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', () => {
    if( delay1 === 0 ) { stage1.update(); delay1 = delay1Start; }
    delay1--;
});
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', () => {
    if( delay2 === 0 ) { stage2.update(); delay2 = delay2Start; }
    delay2--;
});
```